# Need to add Selenium Jar file every time

Tags: java, selenium

Here I have one doubt regarding selenium automation. Have automated one page,  script is working as expected but once it's closed and reopen the same script it's not working and need to add latest 3.0.1 jar file every time. So can you help me to resolve the same. and Am using below the version

Google Chrome Driver = 2.25 Version
Selenium Jar = 2.48.0 Version

Thanks & Regards,
Ayyappan T

Comment: are properly closing DriverManager at the end? also can you post the logs?

Comment: This is the Exception am getting while close and rerun the same code:                 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a free port
 at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.findFreePort(PortProber.java:66)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.build(ChromeDriverService.java:200)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:92)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:106)
 at com.discern.mandatorychecklist.Sample.main(Sample.java:17)

Comment: Are you running multiple tests in  parallel?

Comment: Try checking your host file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc. Either
delete localhost or set it to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: no am using single script only and am facing same problems for all the browser's. and also i did changes localhost details no luck

Comment: Have you tried to set 127.0.0.1 in host file

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the configuration map from /etc/hosts

OR

This worked for me without changing the localhost

First get the process id name by greping port no 1024

```
ps -aux | grep 1024
```

And then kill that process

```
kill -9 PROCESS_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in int /etc/host file of your system:

127.0.0.1 localhost

make sure others are commented out using "#"

It worked for me!!!